# Javascript not displaying in canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I've been creating a Flappy Bird game with JavaScript and for some reason, it's stopped displaying in the browser. I've checked the canvas displays by changing the background colour, but the actual JavaScript doesn't. I'm new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flappy Bird using JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
   <script src="flappyBird.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// load images

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeNorth = new Image();
var pipeSouth = new Image();

bird.src = "images/bird.png";
bg.src = "images/bg.png";
fg.src = "images/fg.png";
pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";
pipeSouth.src = "images/pipeSouth.png";

// some variables

var gap = 85;
var constant = pipeNorth.height+gap;

var bX = 10;
var bY = 150;

var gravity = 1.5;

// on key down

document.addEventListener("keydown",moveUp);

function moveUp(){
  bY -= 25;
}

// pipe coordinates

var pipe = [];

pipe[0] = {
  x : cvs.width;
  y : 0;
}

// draw images

function draw(){
  ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);

  for(var i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++){
    ctx.drawImage(pipeNorth,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y);
    ctx.drawImage(pipeSouth,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y+constant);

    pipe[i].x--;

    if(pipe[i].x == 125){
      pipe.push({
        x : cvs.width,
        y : Math.floor(Math.random()*pipeNorth.height) - pipeNorth.height
      });
    }

    // detect collision

    if(bX + bird.width >= pipe[i].x && bX <= pipe[i].x + pipeNorth.width &&
      (bY <= pipe[i].y + pipeNorth.height || bY+bird.height >= pipe[i].y+constant)
      || bY + bird.height >= cvs.height - fg.height){
      location.reload();
    }

    if(pipe[i].x == 5){
      score++;
    }
  }

  ctx.drawImage(fg,0,cvs.height - fg.height);

  ctx.drawImage(bird,bX,bY);

  bY += gravity;

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.font = "20px Verdana";
  ctx.fillText("Score: "+score,10,cvs.height-20);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. And go read up on the basics of debugging JavaScript.

Comment: You need to remove semi colons here: pipe[0] = {
  x : cvs.width;
  y : 0;
}  and use a comma, then continue debugging

Comment: Thank you guys, I've got it working now!